# GridView in Alert Dialogue Android

Tags: android, gridview

I am trying to add GridView in my alert dialogue from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25351091/8387050) answer.

My current working alert dialogue is using single choice item like below code

```
  private void showGotoPageDialog() {

            if (mTotalPages > 0) {

                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
                builder.setTitle("Go to Page:");
                builder.setSingleChoiceItems(mPageOptions, mPageIndx - 1,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int item) {
                                mOptionDiag.dismiss();
                                mPageIndx = item + 1;
                                updateQuotesListServer();
                                updatePageInfo();
                            }
                        });

                builder.setNegativeButton("Dismiss",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int id) {

                            }
                        });
                mOptionDiag = builder.create();
                mOptionDiag.show();

            }
        }
```

where code used for list is like below

```
 mTotalPages = (int) Math.ceil(totalQuotes / ITEMS_PER_PAGE);
                            mPageIndx = 1;
                            mPageOptions = new String[mTotalPages];
                            for (int i = 1; i <= mTotalPages; i++) {
                                mPageOptions[i - 1] = "Page " + i;
                        }
```

Now I am doing like this for convert above dialogue in GridView like below

```
 private void showGotoPageDialog() {
    //
    //        if (mTotalPages > 0) {

                GridView gridView = new GridView(getActivity());
                List<Integer> mList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for (int i = 1; i<mTotalPages; i++) {
                    mList.add(i-1)= boolean i;
                   /* final int mPageOptions;
                    for (int i = 1; i <= mTotalPages; i++) {
                        mPageOptions[i - 1] = i;
                    }*/
                }
                gridView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mList));
                gridView.setNumColumns(5);
                gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {

                    }
                });


                AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
                        getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogTheme);
                builder.setTitle("Go to Page:");
                builder.setView(gridView);
                builder.show();
```

I am not able to set perfect code for this lines of code in GridView Dialog.

```
for (int i = 1; i<mTotalPages; i++) {
                mList.add(i-1)= boolean i;
```

Let me know if someone can suggest me correct code for it.
Thanks

Comment: where is your `updateQuotesListServer();
                                updatePageInfo();` methods ?

Comment: @sushildlh its function I am calling when user select item. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
     android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(ModifyInforActivity.this);
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dilog_time_picker, null);
                builder.setView(layout);
```